# Transaction (Process ID xx) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, transactionscope

I'm getting a...

```
Transaction (Process ID xx) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

...in the following code. How come?

```
// SIMPLE ORDERNUMBER LOGIC
var orderNumber = 1;
Order order = null;

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    if (db.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderNumber.HasValue))
    {
        // 1. Get the last successful order OrderNumber
        var lastSuccessfulOrder = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderNumber.HasValue).OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderNumber).FirstOrDefault();
        if (lastSuccessfulOrder != null)
        {
            orderNumber = lastSuccessfulOrder.OrderNumber.Value + 1;
        }
    }

    // 2. Create the new order with null values except OrderNumber column
    order = new Order();
    order.OrderNumber = orderNumber;
    db.Orders.Add(order);

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    db.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

I'm looking in SQL Profiler at the Deadlock graph but I can't really understand it to be honest.

The `Thread.Sleep(2000)` I put there to simulate a transaction that takes a little bit longer to process; which btw seems to be the culprit in some way, because when I remove it I don't get any deadlock. Any ideas?

Here are the Deadlock Graphs:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using `Thread.Sleep()` for testing purpose only? Using it to simulate long running transaction seems odd.

Comment: Which isolation level are you using? If you are using Serializable try to change to Read Commited (and if it works think if that affects you some how) If you post your deadlock graph it would be good

Comment: @Kamo Yes. I couldn't come up with other alternatives. Got any suggestions regarding that? Seems odd to me too using it that way in a transaction. Hmm.

Comment: @Juan The default. Which is Serializable.

Comment: @PussInBoots - if you really want to simulate background task running(I believe it is for UI/UX purpose) you could use simple `setTimeout()` using JavaScript(if you are building Web Application).

Comment: Try changing to Read Commited, your read at the beginning and your insert could be doing some funny page lock (depending on your indexes). If you are worried about the OrderNumber thing, try to use Identity on db to avoid problems with the change of isolation level

Comment: @Juan I've added the deadlock graphs from SQL Profiler in my question you requested.

Comment: @Kamo I need to be able to control/test transaction duration length from within TransactionScope using statement. I can't do that with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

So by the deadlocks graphs looks like you are deadlocking because of the Serializable isolation level. Think on this scenario:

1. Request 1 came and read the whole PK index to find out the latest Order Number.Locking it for writes as it is Serializable
2. Request 1 sleeps for 2 seconds
3. Request 2 came and read the whole PK index to find out the latest Order Number.Locking it for writes as it is Serializable
4. Request 2 sleeps for 2 seconds.
5. Request 1 awakes and try to write but the PK index is locked by Request 2 for writes.
6. Request 2 awakes and try to write but the PK index is locked by Request 1 for writes.

There are different ways you can address this, two options here

1. Generate order numbers for all orders not only successful ones. You can do this on the database with an IDENTITY column and you won't need to do that read.
2. Change your Isolation level to Read Committed so the read doesn't block the table, but that means that your read could became "dirty" and you could end up generating duplicated order numbers. You can add a Unique key to handle that on database, and in case the constraint is violated you can retry again.

In general Serializable is not a good scaling isolation level, if you can do it with Read Commited or Read Commited Snapshot isolation levels better.

Also generating incremental Ids on code is better to be left to the database which have different mechanisms to avoid locks.

If you want to have consecutive order numbers (why? having a few gaps shouldn't be a big deal and will save you a lot of hassle) you could have a bottleneck on that order number generation. You could just make your db side single threaded and attend one request at a time so you don't need to even create transactions for this. But obviously you will have a scalability problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not database expert but it might happened that in some of your code some is using same table that does read/write. Try this :

```
TransactionOptions transOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;

var orderNumber = 1;
Order order = null;

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, transOptions))
{
    if (db.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderNumber.HasValue))
    {
        // 1. Get the last successful order OrderNumber
        var lastSuccessfulOrder = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderNumber.HasValue).OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderNumber).FirstOrDefault();
        if (lastSuccessfulOrder != null)
        {
            orderNumber = lastSuccessfulOrder.OrderNumber.Value + 1;
        }
    }

    // 2. Create the new order with null values except OrderNumber column
    order = new Order();
    order.OrderNumber = orderNumber;
    db.Orders.Add(order);

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    db.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

If found this code in this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1615214.aspx?Deadlock%20System%20Data%20SqlClient%20SqlException%20Transaction%20Process%20ID%2051%20was%20deadlocked%20on%20lock%20resources%20with%20another%20process%20and%20has%20been%20chosen%20as%20the%20deadlock%20victim%20) and for [TransactionOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [IsolationLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I hope this will help you some how.

Comment: Yeah that is what I think will fix it. But he will need to address the problem with that code that it can generate duplicated OrderNumber as it is reading the latest one and not locking. A database generated number (Identity or not) makes more sense than doing it manually.

Comment: @Juan I can't use a regular identity column for order numbering since I need to be able to predict the numbering sequence that will get generated. 1,2,3,4,5 etc Using OrderId as the order number could lead to unpredictable results in SQL Server. 1,2,3,4,5 and then suddenly it can jump to 1000,1001,1002 etc. This is by design.

Comment: I'm getting duplicate OrderNumber values using this method. I really need the app to be in that table during that transaction one at a time to not get duplicate OrderNumber values.

Comment: Some suggestions on how to deal with the duplicate order numbers on my answer.